# ListView Image using SimpleCursorAdapter didn't show

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I tried to make a listview using database adapter like what's mentioned in the following [tutorial](http://kholisilkom45.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/membuat-listview-image-dengan-database-sqlite/) :

But when I changed the structure of the database, the listview didn't show.
This is the actual script :

```
try{
 cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tum ORDER BY nama ASC", null);

 adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_lv, cursor, new String[] {"nama", "nama_latin", "img"}, new int[] {R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_nama_latin, R.id.imV});

 lv.setAdapter(adapter);

 lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


 }catch(Exception e){

 e.printStackTrace();

 }
```

This is the script I made according to my own database I made earlier

```
    try{
         dataCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_achievement", null);
         adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_lv, dataCursor, new String[] {"title", "description", "img"}, new int[] {R.id.tv_title, R.id.tv_description, R.id.imV});
         lv.setAdapter(adapter);
         lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


         }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Thank you

Comment: Please translate the second part into English so we can figure out what is going on.

Comment: @AustynMahoney i have translate the second part into english,

Comment: Are your column names `title` `description` and `img`? What does the log say when you run your app and try to call this code?

Comment: can u post u r db structure with column names and the query code